# Storing multi line string as 2d array of chars

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I am trying to store a multiline string as an array of chars.
Essentially the string input is a game board where the '#' are the walls and ' ' are open spaces.
The first line simply specifies that the board is 8x8 chars.

String input as code:

```
            "8\r\n"
            + "########\r\n"
            + "P #    #\r\n"
            + "# # ## #\r\n"
            + "# #  #G#\r\n"
            + "#    ###\r\n"
            + "#### # #\r\n"
            + "#G   #G#\r\n"
            + "########";
```

What i am trying to do is store this multi line string so that i get a 2d array that would store it like this:

```
'#''#''#''#''#''#''#''#'
'P'' ''#'' '' '' '' ''#'
'#'' ''#'' ''#''#'' ''#'
etc..
```

Comment: *I am trying to store* ... actually, so far, you only presented your assignment to other people. We help you with your homework, we dont do it for. So: please include your own efforts and clearly describe where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
String input = "8\r\n"
    + "########\r\n"
    + "P #    #\r\n"
    + "# # ## #\r\n"
    + "# #  #G#\r\n"
    + "#    ###\r\n"
    + "#### # #\r\n"
    + "#G   #G#\r\n"
    + "########";
char[][] result = input.lines()
    .skip(1)
    .map(String::toCharArray)
    .toArray(char[][]::new);
for (char[] line : result)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line));
```

output:

```
[#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]
[P,  , #,  ,  ,  ,  , #]
[#,  , #,  , #, #,  , #]
[#,  , #,  ,  , #, G, #]
[#,  ,  ,  ,  , #, #, #]
[#, #, #, #,  , #,  , #]
[#, G,  ,  ,  , #, G, #]
[#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]
```

Comment: Perfect! @saka1029, I didn't know about lines method of String since Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using Stream API:

```
     String str = "8\r\n"
            + "########\r\n"
            + "P #    #\r\n"
            + "# # ## #\r\n"
            + "# #  #G#\r\n"
            + "#    ###\r\n"
            + "#### # #\r\n"
            + "#G   #G#\r\n"
            + "########";

     char[][] result = Arrays.stream(str.split("\r\n"))
                             .skip(1)
                             .map(String::toCharArray)
                             .toArray(char[][]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

And then there is the non-streams approach.

- Split the line on the line terminator
- Allocate an array of char (`charArray`) to hold all but the first line
- For each of the lines, convert the line to a character array and assign to the `charArray`, ensuring to start with the second line.

```
String[] lines = input.split("\r\n");
char[][] charArray = new char[lines.length-1][];    
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    charArray[i] = lines[i+1].toCharArray();
}
for(char[] c : charArray) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
}
```

Prints

```
[#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]
[P,  , #,  ,  ,  ,  , #]
[#,  , #,  , #, #,  , #]
[#,  , #,  ,  , #, G, #]
[#,  ,  ,  ,  , #, #, #]
[#, #, #, #,  , #,  , #]
[#, G,  ,  ,  , #, G, #]
[#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]
```